# configuring Django urls between project and apps

Tags: python, django

I want to add a accounts app to the mysite/polls project from the Django tutorial. I am not able to get the urls setup properly when I add a 'accounts' app to manage user authentication.

My root URLconf is:

```py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'uniVote.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^elections/', include('elections.urls', namespace='elections')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    # ex: accounts/...
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
)
```

and my URLconf in my accounts app is:

```py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    # ex: /accounts/login/
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'accounts.views.user_login'),
    # ex: /accounts/logout/
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'accounts.views.user_logout'),
    # ex: /accounts/register/
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', 'accounts.views.user_register'),
    )
```

Also, here is my accounts views.py:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

#Import a user registration form
from accounts.forms import UserRegisterForm


# User Login View
def user_login(request):
    if request.user.is_anonymous():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            #This authenticates the user
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    #This logs him in
                    login(request, user)
                else:
                    return HttpResponse("Not active")
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Wrong username/password")
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/")


# User Logout View
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')


# User Register View
def user_register(request):
    if request.user.is_anonymous():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid:
                form.save()
                return HttpResponse('User created succcessfully.')
        else:
            form = UserRegisterForm()
        context = {}
        context.update(csrf(request))
        context['form'] = form
        #Pass the context to a template
        return render_to_response('accounts/register.html', context)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Whenever I point my browser to: 0.0.0.0:8080/accounts/register, I get a 404 error and the following output:

Using the URLconf defined in uniVote.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

1. ^elections/

   ^admin/

   ^accounts/ ^accounts/login/$

   ^accounts/ ^accounts/logout/$

   ^accounts/ ^accounts/register/$

The current URL, accounts/register/, didn't match any of these.

---

From the tutorial, I believed that addr:port/accounts/register would load the root URLconf and see 'accounts' and load the accounts/urls.py and pass 'register' and see the third url pattern and load accounts.views.user_register.

Is there something I am missing to reach the accounts/... urls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you app is configured to view in `accounts/accounts/register/` url.

From your code, the regex of URL has "accounts" repeated.

Basically you should try:

`url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls'))`

and then remove "accounts" from account urls.

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    # ex: /accounts/login/
    url(r'^login/$', 'accounts.views.user_login'),
    # ex: /accounts/logout/
    url(r'^logout/$', 'accounts.views.user_logout'),
    # ex: /accounts/register/
    url(r'^register/$', 'accounts.views.user_register'),
    )
```